# Rails 4.2 - after upgrade, pages never load in browser (or take really long) despite server activity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, ruby-on-rails-4, upgrade

I am in the process of upgrading our app from Rails 3.2 to 4.2. One of the problems I've run into is that even static pages don't seem to be loading in the browser for some reason, despite browser activity. Example: I go to `localhost:3000/pricing` and get this in the server:

```
Started GET "/pricing" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-16 15:44:59 -0500
Processing by PagesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"pricing"}
  Rendered pages/pricing.html.haml within layouts/static (9.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_head.html.haml (64.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navbar.html.haml (4.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_alerts.html.haml (1.0ms)
  Rendered pages/_nav.html.haml (5.3ms)
  Rendered shared/_social_links.html.haml (1.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.haml (6.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 130ms (Views: 123.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

However, the page in the browser itself is just white, the progress circle in the tab is spinning, and nothing is showing up.

Anyone know what might be causing this?

UPDATE

The page loads normally when I set `config.cache_classes = true` in `development.rb`. But this setting is normally `false` in development and wasn't doing this before I upgraded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was being caused by a gem called "rails-dev-tweaks" that is no longer needed in Rails 4. Removing that gem fixed the problem.

Comment: I just upgraded from 4.1 to 4.2. Rails-dev-tweak still seemed doing its job in 4.1, but broke 4.2 a little. Removing it = Superspeed

Answer (score 0):

Your request on the server side seem to have completed in 130ms so this could be a problem with your client browser. Did you try using a different browser or look at the browser console of any javacript errors?

Comment: Yes, I've tried Chrome and Firefox with the same results. There are no errors in the javascript console.